# boton cortar seccion y guardar con javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

hice una pagina web con javascript y estoy necesitando hacer un boton que corte una parte de la pagina en un rango establecido y que lo guarde como imagen, algo asi como un print pero de un tamaño X y sobre una parte establecida unicamente, alguien tiene alguna idea ?[image: que haga un corte asi aprox]

Comment: Buenas! He revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos. 2 - Si llega a ser necesario subir código, procura que sea un [mcve](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), no olvides formatear el código usando [markdown](/editing-help).

Comment: Gracias Dante, lo voy a tener en cuenta, quiero aclarar igual que habia intentado con diversas funciones pero todas me copiaban solo el texto y a pesar de haber buscado no me habia encontrado con canvas, el cual pude modificar y adaptar a mi objetivo, que tengas linda semana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com), es una librería de JavaScript que soporta muchas propiedades CSS y sirve exactamente para eso.

Aquí tienes algunos tutoriales:

- [Youtube (video) - Facultad Autodidacta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ykBMc6HR78)
- [ourcodeworld (web) - Carlos Delgado](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/415/how-to-create-a-screenshot-of-your-website-with-javascript-using-html2canvas)

Comment: Me re sirvió! no seguí los tutoriales, pero hice uno muy parecido después subo el Código terminado por si alguien lo necesito, muchas gracias!

Comment: @mayra Me alegro de que te haya servido!